# How can I get metering with a Nikkor non-CPU 50mm f/2 lens on my Nikon D7000?

Tags: old-lenses, metering

The metering isn't working when I attach a Nikkor non-CPU 50mm f/2 lens on my Nikon D7000 body. Can I use this lens with a D7000?

Comment: I do not have the D7000, but simply try using Manual Mode. It works for some old lenses I have on Canon and Nikon.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "could not set"?  Do you mean it's not using the non-CPU lens data? Or that you can't adjust the aperture from the camera body? Or that metering isn't working as you expect? Or... what?

Comment: Ok. Well, I mean that the metering isn't working when I attaching the lens

Comment: @AniruddhaSen, did you set the aperture of the lens to the minimum setting and lock it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the lens to Non-CPU lens data in the setup menu (spanner icon)? Non-CPU lenses will only work in A or M modes.

Wait, what year is the lens? If it's the [1964-1972 model](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/50mm-f2.htm) it won't work correctly unless it is Ai-converted. If it hasn't been converted, the camera has no way of knowing what aperture the lens is set at. You also risk breaking the aperture-sensing switch on your camera.

Comment: Yes, I added all data in setup menu. Still not respond when I worked in M mode. Now, what shall I do the next?

Comment: What doesn't respond? The metering? The shutter? Something else?